# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS updating

Tags: upgrade, updates

OK, so I haven't upgraded to 14.04 yet. The update service has said nothing about a new LTS and I'm confused ...

Updates keep coming. Some things are working just a little different. I'm trying to deal with longstanding system projects so I'm not tempted to upgrade quite yet.

But should I? Are these piddly updates going to steer me wrong? Will Ubuntu 12.04 LTS just degrade and degrade an degrade? Why isn't update suggesting I go for the newer, brighter, shinier LTS?

Oh, and what is the meaning of life?

Cecilieaux

Answer (score 1):

LTS users will get the notification when the first point release (14.04.1) is release in July.

You could upgrade if you wish but since it seems you're concerned about stability I recommend you wait until July.

12.04 is still receiving updates and will continue to do so for 3 years (until April 2017). So, you're in no hurry.